# Rails Tutorial chapter 10.3.3 - 4 RSpec Errors (app working)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, will-paginate, railstutorial.org

I'm getting 4 RSpec errors that have something to do with the Will-Paginate gem, but for the life of me, I cant figure out what they're pointing at. The app works fine though.

```
Failures:

  1) UsersController GET 'index' for signed-in users should be successful
     Failure/Error: get :index
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `paginate' for #<Class:0x9580710>
     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:7:in `index'
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:30:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) UsersController GET 'index' for signed-in users should have the right title
     Failure/Error: get :index
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `paginate' for #<Class:0x9580710>
     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:7:in `index'
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:35:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) UsersController GET 'index' for signed-in users should have an element for each user
     Failure/Error: get :index
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `paginate' for #<Class:0x9580710>
     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:7:in `index'
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:40:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) UsersController GET 'index' for signed-in users should paginate users
     Failure/Error: get :index
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `paginate' for #<Class:0x9580710>
     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:7:in `index'
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:47:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 3.12 seconds
80 examples, 4 failures
```

My users_controller.rb file:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:index, :edit, :update]
  before_filter :correct_user, :only => [:edit, :update]

  def index
    @title = "All users"
    @users = User.paginate(:page => params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @title = @user.name + "<script>"
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @title = "Sign up"
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      @title = "Sign up"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @title = "Edit user"
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated."
      redirect_to @user
    else
      @title = "Edit user"
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

    def authenticate
      deny_access unless signed_in?
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
    end
end
```

My users_controller_spec.rb file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersController do
  render_views

  describe "GET 'index'" do

    describe "for non-signed-in users" do
      it "should deny access" do
        get :index
        response.should redirect_to(signin_path)
        flash[:notice].should =~ /sign in/i
      end
    end

    describe "for signed-in users" do

      before(:each) do
        @user = test_sign_in(Factory(:user))
        second = Factory(:user, :name => "Bob", :email => "another@example.com")
        third  = Factory(:user, :name => "Ben", :email => "another@example.net")

        @users = [@user, second, third]
        30.times do
          @users << Factory(:user, :email => Factory.next(:email))
        end
      end

      it "should be successful" do
        get :index
        response.should be_success
      end

      it "should have the right title" do
        get :index
        response.should have_selector("title", :content => "All users")
      end

      it "should have an element for each user" do
        get :index
        @users[0..2].each do |user|
          response.should have_selector("li", :content => user.name)
        end
      end

      it "should paginate users" do
        get :index
        response.should have_selector("div.pagination")
        response.should have_selector("span.disabled", :content => "Previous")
        response.should have_selector("a", :href => "/users?page=2",
                                           :content => "2")
        response.should have_selector("a", :href => "/users?page=2",
                                           :content => "Next")
      end     
    end
  end

  describe "Get 'show'" do

    before(:each) do
      @user = Factory(:user)
    end

    it "should be successfull" do
      get :show, :id => @user
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should find the right user" do
      get :show, :id => @user
      assigns(:user).should == @user
    end

     it "should have the right title" do
      get :show, :id => @user
      response.should have_selector("title", :content => @user.name)
    end

    it "should include the user's name" do
      get :show, :id => @user
      response.should have_selector("h1", :content => @user.name)
    end

    it "should have a profile image" do
      get :show, :id => @user
      response.should have_selector("h1>img", :class => "gravatar")
    end
  end

  describe "GET 'new'" do

    it "should be successful" do
      get :new
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
      get :new
      response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Sign up")
    end
  end

  describe "POST 'create'" do
    describe "failure" do

      before(:each) do
        @attr = { :name => "", :email => "", :password => "",
                  :password_confirmation => "" }
      end

      it "should not create a user" do
        lambda do
          post :create, :user => @attr
        end.should_not change(User, :count)
      end

      it "should have the right title" do
        post :create, :user => @attr
        response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Sign up")
      end

      it "should render the 'new' page" do
        post :create, :user => @attr
        response.should render_template('new')
      end
    end

    describe "success" do

      before(:each) do
        @attr = { :name => "New User", :email => "user@example.com", :height => "192cm",
                  :password => "foobar", :password_confirmation => "foobar" }
      end

      it "should create a user" do
        lambda do
          post :create, :user => @attr
        end.should change(User, :count).by(1)
      end

      it "should sign the user in" do
        post :create, :user => @attr
        controller.should be_signed_in
      end

      it "should redirect to the user show page" do
        post :create, :user => @attr
        response.should redirect_to(user_path(assigns(:user)))
      end

      it "should have a welcome message" do
        post :create, :user => @attr
        flash[:success].should =~ /welcome to the sample app/i
      end
    end
  end

  describe "GET 'edit'" do

    before(:each) do
      @user = Factory(:user)
      test_sign_in(@user)
    end

    it "should be successful" do
      get :edit, :id => @user
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
      get :edit, :id => @user
      response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Edit user")
    end

    it "should have a link to change the Gravatar" do
      get :edit, :id => @user
      gravatar_url = "http://gravatar.com/emails"
      response.should have_selector("a", :href => gravatar_url,
                                         :content => "change")
    end
  end

  describe "PUT 'update'" do

    before(:each) do
      @user = Factory(:user)
      test_sign_in(@user)
    end

    describe "failure" do

      before(:each) do
        @attr = { :email => "", :name => "", :password => "",
                  :password_confirmation => "" }
      end

      it "should render the 'edit' page" do
        put :update, :id => @user, :user => @attr
        response.should render_template('edit')
      end

      it "should have the right title" do
        put :update, :id => @user, :user => @attr
        response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Edit user")
      end
    end

    describe "success" do

      before(:each) do
        @attr = { :name => "New Name", :email => "user@example.org",
                  :password => "barbaz", :password_confirmation => "barbaz" }
      end

      it "should change the user's attributes" do
        put :update, :id => @user, :user => @attr
        @user.reload
        @user.name.should  == @attr[:name]
        @user.email.should == @attr[:email]
      end

      it "should redirect to the user show page" do
        put :update, :id => @user, :user => @attr
        response.should redirect_to(user_path(@user))
      end

      it "should have a flash message" do
        put :update, :id => @user, :user => @attr
        flash[:success].should =~ /updated/
      end
    end
  end

  describe "authentication of edit/update pages" do

    before(:each) do
      @user = Factory(:user)
    end

    describe "for non-signed-in users" do

      it "should deny access to 'edit'" do
        get :edit, :id => @user
        response.should redirect_to(signin_path)
      end

      it "should deny access to 'update'" do
        put :update, :id => @user, :user => {}
        response.should redirect_to(signin_path)
      end
    end

    describe "for signed-in users" do

      before(:each) do
        wrong_user = Factory(:user, :email => "user@example.net")
        test_sign_in(wrong_user)
      end

      it "should require matching users for 'edit'" do
        get :edit, :id => @user
        response.should redirect_to(root_path)
      end

      it "should require matching users for 'update'" do
        put :update, :id => @user, :user => {}
        response.should redirect_to(root_path)
      end
    end

  end
end
```

I know its got something to do with defining the paginate method, but I cant find (or understand) anything in the tutorial specific to this. Any help whatsoever is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `will_paginate` gem to your `Gemfile` (and make sure it is in the main part of your `Gemfile`, **not** in a `group :development` block):

```
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.pre2'
```

and then run `bundle install` to make sure it gets installed. Then your specs should pass.

Comment: Maybe not that simple: in the title, it's said the app is working :)

Comment: Maybe the gem's only loading during development mode? We'll see.

Comment: This is embarrassing. All I had to do is add `will_paginate` in the main part of Gemfile, like Dylan said. I previously had it under `group :development do`, contrary to the instructions in Rails Tutorial, which was the problem all along.

Answer (score 0):

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/rails-3-1#sec-will_paginate

should do the trick. There's a bug with that version of will_paginate. It's a quick fix though. Check out the url.