# rspec error: Learn Rails by Example: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am receiving an odd rspec error when walking through the Learn Rails by Example tutorial by Mike Hartl.

On page 419, Listing 10.30: The code is as follows:

```
it "should have an element for each user" do
get :index
@users[0..2].each do |user|
response.should have_selector("li", :content => user.name)
end
end
```

And when I run rspec, I receive this error message.:

Failures:

```
1) UsersController GET 'index' for signed-in-users should have an element for each user
    Failure/Error: @users[0..2].each do |user|
    NoMethodError:
      You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
      You might have expected an instance of Array.
      The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]
    # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:40

Finished in 2.58 seconds 75 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:38 # UsersController GET 'index' for >signed-in-users should have an element for each user
```

I did some research and found similar problems in this thread but I still haven't been able to get the test to pass.

Any ideas?

Reference links:

[Why are my RSpec tests failing, but my app is working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948756/why-are-my-rspec-tests-failing-but-my-app-is-working)

[Cookies do not persist in Rspec on rails 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821692/cookies-do-not-persist-in-rspec-on-rails-3-1)

[Rails Tutorial chapter 10.3.3 - 4 RSpec Errors (app working)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720059/rails-tutorial-chapter-10-3-3-4-rspec-errors-app-working)

Comment: Also, the first link mentions added current_user and @current_user tot he sessions_helper.rb file. I tried this but it doesn't seem to have corrected anything.

Comment: One other comment, the app works fine. Just this one test fails. It is very frustrating!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out.

```
@users[0..2].each do |user|
```

needed to become:

```
User.paginate(:page => 1).each do |user|
```

The app still works with either line but to get rspec test to pass, you need to use User.paginate.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the users are not being created in the test DB. Check you have multiple users in @users by inserting

```
puts @users.length
```

after 'get :index'

If this is nil, you should probably double check your before block.

Comment: It gives me a " You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!" for the @users.lenght